# Codeigniter setting new value to db

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, sql-update

I am working on Basketball Referee project. I am trying to update table checking input value.

I am sending the value from my control.php like this:

```
$check_user = $this->input->post("headreferee");

$check = $this->sql_model->check1($check_user);
```

Here is my sql_model.php:

```
function check1($referee_name)

{

$sql    = "SELECT * FROM duties WHERE username ='{$referee_name}' ";

$query  = $this->db->query($sql);

if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
        $this->db->set('count','count'+1);
        $this->db->insert('duties');    
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Actually it is increasing count and adding new row but without any referee_name. It has to find the correct referee_name and increase that row's count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update so please modify your check1() function by below script.

```
function check1($referee_name)

{

$sql    = "SELECT * FROM duties WHERE username ='{$referee_name}' ";

$query  = $this->db->query($sql);

$result_referee = $query->row();
$countNew = $result_referee->count + 1;
if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
        $countArray = array('count'=>$countNew);
        $this->db->where('username',$referee_name);
        $this->db->update('duties',$countArray);    
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I hope that will be helpful for you as your solution.